# Use Windows Powershell ISE for Exchange when you have MFA

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-remoting

I have been using Windows PowerShell ISE for some time, connecting to Azure AD,Exchange and SharePoint successfully. Recently a change in the organisation was made so we are now using MFA with exchange, I followed this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt775114(v=exchg.160).aspx and everything works as expected.

My question is - Is there a way to use windows PowerShell ISE to run exchange commands now?

Now  it seems I am required to open the Exchange Online Remote PowerShell Module and connect and run any exchange commands through that module. I have tried using `Connect-EXOPSSession` cmdlet in the windows powerShell ISE but it does not understand the cmdlet

[image]
[image]

Comment: [Related link says no](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_exchon/powershell-connect-exopssession-and-ise-debugger/17df04f3-47df-4195-ad4f-06c648091897). I'm curious if someone has found as it should be a case of importing the file where the Cmdlets are defined.

Comment: Thanks for the link, hopefully someone has found a way!

Comment: Create an onmicrosoft.com user on your tenant and use that for this kind of scripting tasks.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but that would still be bound to MFA on my Tenant so I don't think that would change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect exchange online with MFA, you need to install Microsoft's Exchange Online PowerShell Module(EXO).

You can download EXO from Exchange Admin Center.

After installing EXO, exeute below comments in Windows Powershell ISE,

```
$MFAExchangeModule = ((Get-ChildItem -Path $($env:LOCALAPPDATA+"\Apps\2.0\") -Filter CreateExoPSSession.ps1 -Recurse ).FullName | Select-Object -Last 1)
#Importing Exchange MFA Module 
  . "$MFAExchangeModule" 
  Connect-EXOPSSession -UserPrincipalName Admin@Contoso.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I come across the following for importing the Exchange Online module, allowing you to connect using New-ExoPSSession

```bsh
Import-Module $((Get-ChildItem -Path $($env:LOCALAPPDATA+"\Apps\2.0\") -Filter Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellModule.dll -Recurse ).FullName|?{$_ -notmatch "_none_"}|select -First 1)
```